# Mocking an object returned from private method in java

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock

I have a requirement where i want to mock an object that is return from private method. I am working with junit and mockito in my project. I can not paste the actual code here but sample code will look like this. Limitation here is that the code is legacy one and I can not refactor as of now

**Class to test**

```java
 public class TestService {

   public String test() {
     TestDao testDao = getDaoObject();
     int num = testDao.getData();
     if (num < 10) {
       return "hey you loose";
     } else {
       return "hey you win";
     }
   }

   private TestDao getDaoObject() {
     return new TestDao();
   }
 }
```

**Dao Class**

```java
public class TestDao {

  public int getData() {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

**Test class**

```java
 public class JUnitServiceTestExample {
   @Test
   public void test() {
     TestDao testDao = Mockito.mock(TestDao.class);
     TestService test = new TestService();
     when(testDao.getData()).thenReturn(20);
     assertEquals(test.test(), "hey you win");
   }
 }
```

Please help

Comment: Is there any particular reason to why the method has to be private? If not simply make it `protected` and overwrite it in your test so you can  return your desired TestDAO(-Mock).

Comment: If I make the method protected/default, can you tell me how can I get mocked TestDao object @L.Spillner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slightly modify the `getDaoObject` from `private` to `package-private` like below:

```java
TestDao getDaoObject() {
   return new TestDao();
}
```

Then use `Mockito.spy(new TestService())` to stub the `getDaoObject()` and return your mocked `testDao`.

```java
 public class JUnitServiceTestExample {
   @Test
   public void test() {
     TestDao testDao = Mockito.mock(TestDao.class);
     TestService test = Mockito.spy(new TestService());
     when(testDao.getData()).thenReturn(20);
     doReturn(testDao).when(test).getDaoObject();

     String result = test.test();

     assertEquals("hey you win", result);
   }
 }
```

And a tip for you: the correct usage of `assertEquals` is `assertEquals(expected, actual)` not `assertEquals(actual, expected)`